# VB.NET object initialization syntax basics

Tags: vb.net

In VB.NET, I am looking at a line of code that passes the following value to a procedure that defines the parameter as type "object."

```
New Object() {gClient.ContactManager, LyncUri}
```

Here's the complete relevant code

```
Dim gClient As Microsoft.Lync.Model.LyncClient
gClient = Microsoft.Lync.Model.LyncClient.GetClient()

    gClient.ContactManager.BeginSearch(LyncUri,
        Ly.SearchProviders.GlobalAddressList,
        Ly.SearchFields.EmailAddresses,
        Ly.SearchOptions.IncludeContactsWithoutSipOrTelUri,
        1,
        AddressOf SearchCallback,
        New Object() {gClient.ContactManager, LyncUri})
```

and procedure definition

```
Public Function BeginSearch(searchString As String, providers As Microsoft.Lync.Model.SearchProviders, searchFields As Microsoft.Lync.Model.SearchFields, searchOptions As Microsoft.Lync.Model.SearchOptions, maxResults As UInteger, contactsAndGroupsCallback As System.AsyncCallback, state As Object) As System.IAsyncResult
```

I have seen object initializer code that initializes properties of an object by assigning properties values within the brackets using the syntax format of {property1 = value1, property2 = value}, for example but what exactly is the above code doing?

Comment: It creates an array. Example: `Dim obj As String() = New String() {"MyObj1", "MyObj2", "MyObj2"}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`New Object()` creates an *array* of objects.  What's between the { braces } is what initializes the *elements* of the array.  Very convenient syntax sugar for the verbose:

```
dim arr = New Object(1)
arr(0) = gClient.ContactManager
arr(1) = LyncUri
```